# How to silently uninstall then reinstall Quicktime remotely/programattically

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, automated-install

We have a Scholastic program that uses Quicktime to do audio playback and recording.  Unfortunately for me, when I created my image, I didn't know that installing too high a version of Quicktime would break the program.  So now I'm faced with having to go to each computer and uninstall the current version, then install an older version in order to get the program to work.  (I've already tried to install the older version on top and the install fails).

So the question is, is there a way silently uninstall the newer version, then install the older version through GPO or some script?

I have the computers grouped into logical OUs, which should help.

Need to uninstall Quicktime version 7.6.7 and install 7.1.6

I have a Win2k8 domain, and the client computers are XP SP3.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly why everything should be managed through a configuration management system ;-): You must be able to install *and* uninstall/rollback changes.

We use [wpkg](http://wpkg.org), lots of people use the Microsoft Server Manager or Altiris. Wpkg does not require a Windows server, it runs perfectly off a samba share and is open source software.

The wpkg wiki has quite a large section dedicated to silent (un)installers. They have one for [quicktime](http://wpkg.org/Quicktime), you can probably get some ideas about how to script the solution to your problem. I would probably use the startup scripts you can use in a [gpo](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/permissions/adding-startup-scripts-to-gpos.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I hear you about management systems.  We're still playing catch up in the environments, after 10 years of contractor work.  So needless to say, things are not really seamless around here yet.....

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use "msiexec /x" to uninstall Quicktime, since Apple has been using Microsoft's installer tools for a while (don't let the .exe fool you).

A nice little article about MSI and Quicktime can be found here:
http://www.msiwisdom.com/index.php/articles-mainmenu-2/apple/183-apple-quicktime-76775

You may have to actually put the newer Quicktime MSI file on the box (or make it accessible) to run the MSI uninstall process, but it absolutely should be possible to do the install using standard MS-MSI practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was able to use to make it work on a 64-bit Win10 machine, your results may vary, but this worked for me:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe /x {216AB108-2AE1-4130-B3D5-20B2C4C80F8F} /qn
```

Before getting yelled at for reviving a dead post, I found this on Google while trying to figure out how to batch uninstall QT after the recent revelations about QT being vulnerable and needing to be removed in a hurry.  If this can help anybody, then I will be glad to have helped out.  I am sure that OP has moved on in the last 6 years.