# Mass deployment of Adobe Reader v10, removal of older versions

Tags: deployment

I'm not familiar with any software deployment tools we have here.  It is a Windows domain with a Server 2003 domain controller.

The majority of remote and office PCs have versions of Acrobat Reader older than v10, and I want to remove them, and install v10.

Does MS provide any tools to do this?  If not, are there free free deployment tools?  We have a copy of the offline installer file on one of our servers.

Answer (score 1):

Not a free tool, but for $20/month, well worth it:

[Ninite Pro](https://ninite.com/pro)

Just script it to run at startup via group policy. It's pretty awesome :-)

Comment: I think I could kiss you.

Comment: That's the most interesting little tool I've seen in a while.  I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Adobe Hell.

Does MS provide tools to add/remove 3rd party software?  Kind of.  But then you're looking at creating your own MSI packages, among other things.  There are free deployment tools.  You can look at my question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/179905/how-to-silently-uninstall-then-reinstall-quicktime-remotely-programattically) and take a look at some of the answers provided.  You might get lucky and find a tool to that will remove the old one and install the new one.  Otherwise you're looking at scripts and other fun activities.  Do a search adobe and scripting on this site, and I'm sure you'll find other useful nuggets.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the documentation that Adobe provides for Enterprise environments.  What you're looking for can be done.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/837/cpsid_83709.html

The specific document that will likely answer your questions can be found here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/837/cpsid_83709/attachments/Acrobat_Enterprise_Administration.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I found some other answers and it looks like [**WPKG**](http://wpkg.org/) will do the job.